# Saving Angular Dist Folder In Source Control

Tags: git, angular, typescript, build, version-control

Should we keep the `dist` folder in Source Control such as git in Angular => 2? Why and why not?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you like to store generated content, which instantly gets outdated when someone change one line of code?

It is the responsibility of a build server to build the app to a dist folder, running e2e tests, deploy it and so on.

Comment: I also have same thought but are there any General build server configurations?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question.. Can you provide more detail in what you mean?

Comment: That's what I thought, too. However, the docs for npm version (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version) suggest this as one of the lines in their script section: ["version": "npm run build && git add -A dist"]. Why would npm version want to check in the dist directory?

Answer (score 1):

The **bin** folder which has dll is not put under source control (git).

**dist** folder which contains the concatenated and compressed js files could be considered as bin folder. The files could be generated at any time so no need to put under source control.

Answer (score 0):

Generally not, as there is no need. It can easily be reproduced by running the `ng build` command